# Histogram at specific coordinates inside axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6

What I want to achieve with Python 3.6 is something like this :
[image: Histogram and scatter on same axes]

Obviously made in paint and missing some ticks on the xAxis. Is something like this possible? Essentially, can I control **exactly** where to plot a histogram (and with what orientation)?

I specifically want them to be on the **same** axes just like the figure above and not on separate axes or subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax2Handler = fig.gca()
ax2Handler.scatter(np.array(np.arange(0,len(xData),1)), xData)
ax2Handler.hist(xData,bins=60,orientation='horizontal',normed=True)
```

This and other approaches (of inverting the axes) gave me no results. xData is loaded from a panda dataframe.

```
# This also doesn't work as intended
fig = plt.figure()
axHistHandler = fig.gca()
axScatterHandler = fig.gca()
axHistHandler.invert_xaxis()
axHistHandler.hist(xData,orientation='horizontal')
axScatterHandler.scatter(np.array(np.arange(0,len(xData),1)), xData)
```

Comment: Its possible to create both that scatter and hist in the same Axes. I'm not sure how to do the procedure in 3D but I'm also unsure why you even want to display information like that.

Comment: This question is not well suited for SO. Limit your question to one specific problem. It is clearly possible to draw a histogram into the same axes as a scatter plot. But there is also next to no reason to do it and working with 2 different axes is much easier. If you want help with that part, remove everthing that is unrelated (the 3D stuff) and show what you have tried and in how far it failed. As for plotting bars and scatters in 3D, this is a totally different thing, it would still be possible, but by other means than in the 2D case, so ask a different question about it.

Comment: I know the 3D one looks very weird and unpractical (due to its orientation), but I'm trying to plot more data/histograms in a 3D space and this is the basic skill I need to accomplish that. I removed the 3D part of the question and will post it separately. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A. using two axes

There is simply no reason not to use two different axes. The plot from the question can easily be reproduced with two different axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
xData = np.random.rand(1000)

fig,(ax,ax2)= plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

ax2.scatter(np.linspace(0,1,len(xData)), xData, s=9)
ax.hist(xData,bins=60,orientation='horizontal',normed=True)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", left=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### B. using a single axes

Just for the sake of answering the question: In order to plot both in the same axes, one can shift the bars by their length towards the left, effectively giving a mirrored histogram.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")
xData = np.random.rand(1000)

fig,ax= plt.subplots(ncols=1)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

ax.scatter(np.linspace(0,1,len(xData)), xData, s=9)
xlim1 = ax.get_xlim()
_,__,bars = ax.hist(xData,bins=60,orientation='horizontal',normed=True)

for bar in bars:
    bar.set_x(-bar.get_width())

xlim2 = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(-xlim2[1],xlim1[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/) jointplots:

```
# Import and fake data
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.randn(2,1000)
# actual plot
jg = sns.jointplot(data[0], data[1], marginal_kws={"bins":100})
jg.ax_marg_x.set_visible(False) # remove the top axis
plt.subplots_adjust(top=1.15) # fill the empty space
```

produces this:
[image]

See more examples of [bivariate distribution representations](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-bivariate-distributions), available in Seaborn.